# Java Printing ArrayList of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, printing

I am trying to print my arraylist but i don't know why my printing does not print line by line of IntegerPair in each index of Adjlist:

```
 private ArrayList<ArrayList<IntegerPair>> AdjList; //outer arraylist 
 private ArrayList<IntegerPair> storeNeighbour; //inner arraylist
 private IntegerPair pair;
```

This is my snippet:

```
for (ArrayList<IntegerPair> l1 : AdjList) {
  for (IntegerPair n : l1) {
    System.out.println( n + "# ");
  }     
}
```

Comment: Can you add your expected output and the output you are currently getting to the question?

Comment: And what is the output? Something like `IntegerPair@...`? If so, read JavaDoc for `Object.toString()` ;-)

Comment: the code looks to work, are those lists empty???

Comment: What is `IntegerPair` class? Is it yours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behavior of ArrayList.toString() is to return a single string containing a (somewhat) beautified list of calls to `toString()` on each element in the list.

So, long story short: you are almost there; the one thing that is missing:

```
@Override 
public String toString() {
...
```

within your class IntegerPair.

Like:

```
public class IntegerPair {
  private final Integer first;
  private final Integer second;
  ...
  @Override 
  public String toString() { 
    return "(" + first + "/" + second ")";
  }
```

or something alike. Without overriding `toString()` your class will fall back on the default implementation given in java.lang.Object; and that method returns class name + hashcode number (and is thus not so human-readable).

Answer (score 0):

Here :

```
for (ArrayList<IntegerPair> l1 : AdjList) {
    for (IntegerPair n : l1) {
        System.out.println( n + "# ");
    }       
}
```

You don't differentiate each printed List.
As a result, you will have a series of output without knowing those associated to a same list.

A more readable print would be :

```
for (ArrayList<IntegerPair> l1 : AdjList) {
    System.out.println("ArrayList with :");
    for (IntegerPair n : l1) {
        System.out.println( n + "# ");
    }       
}
```

You don't specify your output. So I don't suppose `toString()` is or not overridden. If it is not overridden you should either override it to render the String expected here :   `System.out.println( n + "# ");`, or you should specify the content to render here :

```
System.out.println( n.getOne() + "," + n.getOther()  + "# ");
```

As a side note, `toString()` is designed for debugging/logging, not for displaying functional messages as an object could be rendered in a way for a case and in another way for other cases.